# "DataObjects::IntegrityError (ERROR: null value in column violates not-null constraint" error in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datamapper

In my model I have

```
    class Alias
  include DataMapper::Resource


  belongs_to :user


  property :id, String, :key => true, :required => true, :unique => true

  validates_format_of :id, :with => /[0-9a-z\-]/i
```

end

In my controller:

```
def new
   @new_alias = @owner.aliases.new()
end
    def create 
         @owner = current_user
         @alias = @owner.aliases.create(params[:alias])
end
```

And in my view

```
<%= form_for @new_alias, :url => {:controller => "aliases", :action=>"create"} do |f| %> 
    <%= f.text_field :id, :placeholder => "Account name" %></br>
    <%= f.submit :value => "Create" %>
 <% end %>
```

For me it looks preatty normal, but when I'm trying to save new alias, it results with with:

```
ERROR:  null value in column "alias_id" violates not-null constraint
```

> Processing by AliasesController#create
>   as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"/token=",
>   "alias"=>{"id"=>"IDNAME"},
>   "commit"=>"Create"}  ~   SQL (0.632ms)
>   SELECT "id", "encrypted_password",
>   "remember_created_at",
>   "reset_password_token",
>   "reset_password_sent_at",
>   "failed_attempts", "unlock_token",
>   "locked_at", "sign_in_count",
>   "current_sign_in_at",
>   "last_sign_in_at",
>   "current_sign_in_ip",
>   "last_sign_in_ip", "username",
>   "email", "name", "country" FROM
>   "users" WHERE "id" IN (2) LIMIT 1  ~
>   SQL (0.491ms)  SELECT "id" FROM
>   "aliases" WHERE "id" = 'IDNAME' ORDER
>   BY "id" LIMIT 1 Completed   in 11ms  ~
>   SQL (0.531ms)  INSERT INTO "aliases"
>   ("id", "user_id") VALUES ('IDNAME', 2)
>   ~ ERROR:  null value in column
>   "alias_id" violates not-null
>   constraint  (code: 33575106, sql
>   state: 23502, query: INSERT INTO
>   "aliases" ("id", "user_id") VALUES
>   ('IDNAME', 2), uri:
>   postgres:name@localhost:5432postgres?adapter=postgres&host=localhost&port=5432&username=name&password=pass&database=postgres&path=postgres&schema_search_path=public&encoding=utf8&template=template0)
>
> DataObjects::IntegrityError (ERROR: 
>   null value in column "alias_id"
>   violates not-null constraint ):
>   app/controllers/aliases_controller.rb:5:in
>   `create'

What could be the problem? I'm using rails3, postgres and datamapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not familiar with rails internals, but your column's definition must be so that it allow null values.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have fields in your database that aren't defined in your model, and that some of those fields have not-null constraints on them.  Because datamapper only writes the fields it knows about (in this case `:id`), it does not specify values for any additional fields that might exist in the table.  Since the unspecified fields require values, PgSQL is producing an error.

Either remove the not-null constraints, or add those fields to DataMapper with `:default` values on them.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with data mapper.
This is what I did to fix it:

In **Alias** class, add an additional line as follows:

```
property :user_id, Integer
```

This line defines the foreign key.